# Can Json records in a ng-repeat angular loop be linkable to their own unique page views?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json file in the root of my angularjs application. I’m able to view this data in one of my webpages which is perfect, but I would like to expand on this and be able to make each name showing up linkable to a separate page where other more detailed information comes up based on the ID or record chosen. 
My questions are,

1.) Is it possible to accomplish what I’m asking without using a database? If it’s not possible, can you point me to a resource that shows how this is done using Laravel and Angular?

2.) If this is possible to do this with just Angular can you please show me an example on how to do this?

```
//team.html

    <div class="whitecontainer">

<div>




    <h1>Aguiluchos Team Roster</h1><input type="text" data-ng-model="searchTeam">

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AguiluchosCtrl"> 


    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>
          Position 
        </td>
        <td>
          Number 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in Names | filter:searchTeam">
        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Position }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Number }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>  
</div>
</div>

/app.js

latestAguiluchosApp.controller('AguiluchosCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("scripts/aguiluchos.json")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.Names = response.records;});
});

   /aguiluchos.json

  { 

"records":
[ 
{"Name":"Alejandro, Barajas","Position":"GK","Number":29}, 
{"Name":"Devin, Collins","Position":"M","Number":12}, 
{"Name":"Derek, Drodrill","Position":"D","Number":3}, 
{"Name":"Devante, Dubose","Position":"D","Number":18}, 
{"Name":"Matheus, Freire","Position":"M","Number":16}, 
{"Name":"Jesus, Gomez","Position":"GK","Number":20},  
{"Name":"Kevin, Gonzalez","Position":"GK","Number":"NA"},  
{"Name":"Ricardo, Guerra","Position":"M","Number":24}, 
{"Name":"Allan, Gutierrez","Position":"D","Number":4}, 
{"Name":"Hany, Helmy","Position":"M","Number":7}, 
{"Name":"Alejandro, Jauregui","Position":"M","Number":17}, 
{"Name":"Jesus, Leon","Position":"D","Number":21},  
{"Name":"Julio, Lopez","Position":"M","Number":19}, 
{"Name":"Jose, Majano","Position":"GK","Number":1}, 
{"Name":"Adan, Martinez","Position":"D","Number":8},
{"Name":"Benjamin, Middlemiss","Position":"M","Number":13}, 
{"Name":"Ross, MIddlemiss","Position":"F","Number":2}, 
{"Name":"Michael, Molinari","Position":"M","Number":6}, 
{"Name":"Juan, Mondragon","Position":"D","Number":26}, 
{"Name":"Jesus, Morales","Position":"M","Number":11}, 
{"Name":"Leopoldo, Morales","Position":"M","Number":"NA"}, 
{"Name":"Greivin, Pacheco","Position":"F","Number":9}, 
{"Name":"Jose, Prieto","Position":"D","Number":23}, 
{"Name":"Noel, Prieto","Position":"F","Number":"NA"}, 
{"Name":"Flavio, Ramos","Position":"M","Number":"NA"}, 
{"Name":"Simon, Rawnsley","Position":"F","Number":5}, 
{"Name":"Miguel, Santiago","Position":"M","Number":22}, 
{"Name":"Drew, Scafani","Position":"D","Number":14}, 
{"Name":"Alejandro, Sorto","Position":"F","Number":15}, 
{"Name":"Ryan, Trutner","Position":"M","Number":"NA"}  
] 

}
```

Thank you,

Sincerely,

Jesus

Comment: The details that would present on the new page should come from you array at the bottom of your code?

Comment: Yes, for example I could call Name, Position, or Number and have those values show up. To answer your question, the details do come from the array at the bottom. 

If you really think about it, a JSON file is nothing more than a collection of objects. Everything in {} is an object. Objects are simply value pairs.